# QT CREATOR - where do I put the /NODEFAULTLIB:library?

Tags: c++, qt, linker

QT gives the errors

```
LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
```

where do I put the /NODEFAULTLIB:library ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resolving LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007312/resolving-lnk4098-defaultlib-msvcrt-conflicts-with)

Comment: @Mgetz Where do i put /NODEFAULTLIB:library ?

Comment: there is an ignore default libraries setting under the linker settings

Comment: @Mgetz I cannot find any linker settings in Qt Creator 2.6.2

Comment: Ah... I can't help you there I can only speak to visual studio

Comment: This might be covered in the [Qt FAQs](http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/msvcrtd.libcinitexe.obj_warning_lnk4098_defaultlib_msvcrt.lib_conflicts_wit).  But if you [need to add compiler options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614049/adding-extra-compiler-option-in-qt), here's how

Comment: You didn't spell the library name correctly, fyi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell this is a undocumented feature, but this is where you put it in QT Creator 2.6.2 w/ QT 4.8.4 (in the .pro file)

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../LIBRARYNAME/Lib/ -lLIBRARY /NODEFAULTLIB:library
```

Comment: it's not an undocumented feature as much as it is simply a "less obvious way" of passing additional arguments to the compiler/makefile -- but congrats anyway!

Answer (score 4):

Some one with your very issue posted something on the [Qt forums a while back](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/31073-defaultlib-LIBCMT-conflicts-with-use-of-other-libs-use-NODEFAULTLIB-library).

Which sounds like passing in one of the [additional options should help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3%28VS.80%29.aspx).

So in your .pro file:

```
// This
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /MD

// Or that
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /MT
```

And don't forget to run qmake to make sure the makefile arguments absorb the changes made to the .pro file.

Comment: thanks for the help! this didn't work out it helped me figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it under Qt5:

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += /NODEFAULTLIB:LIBCMT
```