# Qt Creator: Treat warnings as errors

Tags: c++, qt-creator

In Visual Studio there is an option to tell the compiler to treat warnings as errors, how do I set that using Qt Creator (I'm using VS2008 as the compiler).

Comment: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6614049/2513200) may contain hints.

Comment: @Hulk Thanks, but it doesn't say how to enable warnings as errors, only how to specify additional compiler options.

Comment: Well if you can add compiler options I assume this one will help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thxezb7y%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: In case anyone else stumbled across this question when a project was failing to compile but not displaying any actual compile errors and just warnings, there's a good chance one of your pre-build or post-build actions is failing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For both compilers (VS and MinGW) use:

```
win32-g++ {
   QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Werror
}
win32-msvc*{
   QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /WX
}
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to adding "QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+=-Werror" to your .pro file is to add it to *build configuration* via the "Projects" tab.

[image: adding cxxflag in qt creator]

This setting will be stored in .pro.user file.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to add

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /WX
```

to my .pro file.